# Powerset with frozenset in Python

Tags: python

I'm sitting here for almost 5 hours trying to solve the problem and now I'm hoping for your help.

Here is my Python Code:

```
   def powerset3(a):

       if (len(a) == 0):
           return frozenset({})
       else:
           s=a.pop()
           b=frozenset({})
           b|=frozenset({})
           b|=frozenset({s})
           for subset in powerset3(a):

              b|=frozenset({str(subset)})
              b|=frozenset({s+subset})
           return b
```

If I run the program with:

```
    print(powerset3(set(['a', 'b'])))
```

I get following solution

```
    frozenset({'a', 'b', 'ab'})
```

But I want to have

```
    {frozenset(), frozenset({'a'}), frozenset({'b'}), frozenset({'b', 'a'})}
```

I don't want to use libraries and it should be recursive!

Thanks for your help

Comment: I presume you want to do this without using any libraries?

Comment: Yes without libraries and recursive!

Comment: You should add that to your question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more readable implementation using `itertools`, if you don't want to use a lib for the combinations, you can replace the combinations code with its implementation e.g. from https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

```
def powerset(l):
    result = [()]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        result += itertools.combinations(l, i+1)
    return frozenset([frozenset(x) for x in result])
```

Testing on IPython, with different lengths

```
In [82]: powerset(['a', 'b'])
Out[82]:
frozenset({frozenset(),
           frozenset({'b'}),
           frozenset({'a'}),
           frozenset({'a', 'b'})})

In [83]: powerset(['x', 'y', 'z'])
Out[83]:
frozenset({frozenset(),
           frozenset({'x'}),
           frozenset({'x', 'z'}),
           frozenset({'y'}),
           frozenset({'x', 'y'}),
           frozenset({'z'}),
           frozenset({'y', 'z'}),
           frozenset({'x', 'y', 'z'})})

In [84]: powerset([])
Out[84]: frozenset({frozenset()})
```

Answer (score 0):

You sort of have the right idea.  If `a` is non-empty, then the powerset of `a` can be formed by taking some element `s` from `a`, and let's called what's left over `rest`.  Then build up the powerset of `s` from the powerset of `rest` by adding to it, for each `subset` in `powerset3(rest)` both `subset` itself and `subset | frozenset({s})`.

That last bit, doing `subset | frozenset({s})` instead of string concatenation is half of what's missing with your solution.  The other problem is the base case.  The powerset of the empty set is *not* the empty set, is the set of one element containing the empty set.

One more issue with your solution is that you're trying to use `frozenset`, which is immutable, in mutable ways (e.g. `pop()`, `b |= something`, etc.)

Here's a working solution:

```
from functools import partial

def helper(x, accum, subset):
    return accum | frozenset({subset}) | frozenset({frozenset({x}) | subset})

def powerset(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return frozenset({frozenset({})})
    else:
        # this loop is the only way to access elements in frozenset, notice
        # it always returns out of the first iteration
        for x in xs:
            return reduce(partial(helper, x), powerset(xs - frozenset({x})), frozenset({}))        

a = frozenset({'a', 'b'})
print(powerset(a))
```